# Can't get meeting of outgoing message in Outlook applescript

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I want to get meeting of a meeting message from Sent Items folder with AppleScript.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set myFolder to folder "Sent Items" of default account
    set meetingList to (every meeting message whose (is read is true)) of myFolder
    
    repeat with theMeeting in meetingList
        set meetingType to type of theMeeting
    end repeat
end tell
```

but the I got this  error:

```
error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t get type of outgoing message id 783." number -1728 from type of outgoing message id 783
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like meeting message class inherits form incoming message and not outgoing message. so it's not possible to get meeting message for outgoing emails.

```
meeting message n [inh. incoming message > message > todoable object > categorizable object > object > …] : A meeting message recieved by the user.
```

however, I find another solution to use Calendar Suite APIs directly which is a lot better with events processing.